# Symfony2 IvoryCKEditorBundle - CK Editor not showing

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, ckeditor

I am trying to display the CK Editor within my textarea form without success :(. I've already searched in github, symfony doc, IvoryCKEditorBundle etc. and still cannot figure out why it doesn't show for me.

I've installed:

- Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
- Ivory\FormExtraBundle\IvoryFormExtraBundle()
- assets

Here is my config:

```
ivory_ck_editor:
  enable: true
  autoload: false
  async: true
  base_path:            bundles/ivoryckeditor/
  js_path:              bundles/ivoryckeditor/ckeditor.js
  default_config:       ~
  configs:
    my_config:
        toolbar: full
        uiColor: "#000000"
        extraPlugins: "wordcount"
    name: []
  plugins:
      name:
        path: ~
        filename: ~
  styles:
      name: []
```

Here is a class with the form:

```
class MatchScheduleType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('content', CKEditorType::class,
                    array('label' => 'content',
                          'required' => false,
                          'config_name' => 'my_config',
                          'trim' => true
                    )
            )
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'saveButtonValue'));
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => 'fcHlinskoBundle\Entity\MatchSchedule',
```

I have a simple entity MatchSchedule.. 
Then i try to pass the form from controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $post = new MatchSchedule();
    $form = $this->createForm(MatchScheduleType::class, $post, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('homepage'),
        'method' => 'POST',
      ));

    return $this->render('fcHlinskoBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
  }
// ...
```

And display it inside a twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_javascript(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And i got this result in html code:

```
<form name="match_schedule" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/">

<script type="text/javascript">        

    if (CKEDITOR.instances["match_schedule_content"]) { delete CKEDITOR.instances["match_schedule_content"]; }

    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("name", "/", "");

    if (CKEDITOR.stylesSet.get("name") === null) { CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add("name", []); }

    CKEDITOR.replace("match_schedule_content", {"toolbar":[["Source","-","NewPage","Preview","Print","-","Templates"],["Cut","Copy","Paste","PasteText","PasteFromWord","-","Undo","Redo"],["Find","Replace","-","SelectAll","-","Scayt"],...... etc.

    </script>


    <div><label for="match_schedule_content">obsah</label>    <textarea id="match_schedule_content" name="match_schedule[content]"></textarea>

    </div><div><button type="submit" id="match_schedule_save" name="match_schedule[save]">odeslat</button></div><input type="hidden" id="match_schedule__token" name="match_schedule[_token]" value="E-zJ2sUyfDIxGP3gljVQGpj8FWId3a8_FIJw3rLkOYU" /></form>
```

All of this results just in simple default textarea with label a submit button.
No CK Editor. Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong? I am really out of ideas, thx for every advice :)